# How do I change the Fee Amount display in CiviEvent registration?

Tags: civievent

The fee amount is displaying too many zeros. Every time I set the fee amount for an event, for example $55.00, a bunch of zeros gets added to the end ... $55.000000. I've reviewed all of the localization settings and everything appears to be set us as described for USD display. I've attached a screenshot of the issue. [image]

Comment: Can you mention CiviCRM version and CMS you are using?

Comment: if you can't replicate this on one of the civicrm demo sites then it could be theming on your site

Comment: eg on http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar problem with php 7.2, Wordpress 5.0.3 and Civicrm 5.9.1.
I ended up adding a javascript function to my website's javascript file. The meat of the function is `number.toFixed(2)` This forces the number to have only two decimal places.

```
function formatPrices() {
        const price_spans = document.querySelectorAll('.crm-price-amount-amount');
        if (!price_spans) {
            return;
        }

        price_spans.forEach(function(node) {
            const price = node.innerText;
            const data = price.split(' ');
            const symbol = data[0];
            const num = +data[1];
            const new_price = symbol + num.toFixed(2);
            node.innerText = new_price;
        });
    }
```

Comment: Could you say where you're experiencing this problem?  Back when the OP wrote this, CiviCRM had recently added support for more significant digits in currency (to support cryptocurrencies better), but in general we thought we stamped out all the places where it shows too many zeroes for "regular" currencies.  If you tell us where this happened, we can fix it for everyone.

Comment: I recently upgraded to Wordpress 5.1 and Civicrm  5.10.4. I was having the problem on public facing event pages. However, I just now disabled the javascript function and loaded an event page, and now I don't see the problem. So I guess ... it isn't a problem anymore :)

Comment: Well, I spoke too soon. I'm still seeing the problem on the registration pages. I would upload a screenshot, but I guess I'm not allowed to.

Comment: I'm also seeing the problem on the Configure Event > Fees tab under "Regular Fees". I took a look on the civi demo site and cannot duplicate the problem there.